# How to store tables, columns and filters as templates

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server

I am able to create standard reports using SSRS which work perfectly, but now I need to create ADHOC reporting engine/solution, we can't use standard SSRS report builder because of following reasons,

- It looks awful and is very difficult to integrate it with our web application
- Our web app is multi tenant so we have issues with security, we can't let our client decide on data sources, data sets directly etc.. They just want to select available Tables, Columns and generate reports.

Here is a prototype I want to develop,

[image]

I am really struggling with following questions,

- How should I store selected tables, columns in database as template, just struggling to find a way to do it.

I am using EntityFramework and SQL Server with asp.net.

Comment: Considered retrieving the schema of the involved tables and save it as XML ? That is the usual way, if i remember correctly, with this You can save the tables schemata and also the data inside the tables. For the Filter You might need to create an own table, consisting of 4 fields, like table name, column name, column type and filter value, once You save the values inside this table, You can also serialize this.